# p values for random effects in lmer

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, p-value, random-effects

I am working on a mixed model using lmer function. I want to obtain p-values for all the fixed and random effects. I am able to obtain p-values for fixed effects using different methods but I haven't found anything for random effects. Whatever method I have found on the internet is to make a null model for the same and then get the p-values by comparison. Can I have a method through which I don't need to make an another model?
My model looks like:

```
mod1 = lmer(Out ~ Var1 + (1 + Var2 | Var3), data = dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do these through model comparison, as far as I know. The `lmerTest` package has a function called `step`, which will reduce your model to just the significant parameters (fixed and random) based on a number of different tests. The documentation isn't entirely clear on how everything is done, so I much prefer to use model comparison to get at specific tests.

For your model, you could test the random slope by specifying:

```
mod0 <- lmer(Out ~ Var1 + (1 + Var2 | Var3), data = dataset, REML=TRUE)
mod1 <- lmer(Out ~ Var1 + (1 | Var3), data = dataset, REML=TRUE)
anova(mod0, mod1, refit=FALSE)
```

This will show you the log likelihood test and test statistic (chi-square distributed). But you are testing two parameters here: the random slope of Var2 and the covariance between the random slopes and random intercepts. So you need a p-value adjustment:

```
1-(.5*pchisq(anova(mod0,mod1, refit=FALSE)$Chisq[[2]],df=2)+
   .5*pchisq(anova(mod0,mod1, refit=FALSE)$Chisq[[2]],df=1))
```

More on those tests [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848728468) or [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466560991).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I am looking for an answer where I don't need a comparison. In the search for the same, I have got a new approach. Kindly comment on it whether I am doing right or not. Here is the method:
I am calculating random effects coeffs using ranef() function and standard errors for the same using se.ranef() function under arm package. Now, coefficients/standard errors will give me the t-values. Using 2 * pt(-abs(tval.ranefs), df = dof), I am calculating the p-values. The only doubt I am having is about dof. Can you suggest me, what should I take as dof for random effects?